# What does MatGetOwnershipRange() do for sequential matrices?

Tags: petsc

I'm writing a petsc code using a sequential matrix type. Since I want it to be easy to parallelize, I put some stuff in the code that is useless now, but will make it easier to parallelize later.

One of the things I added was `MatGetOwnershipRange()` to define the range of iterators that I'm using to build a matrix. The matrix is of type MatSeqAIJ, and has not had any values assigned to it, though memory has been allocated with `MatSeqAIJSetPreallocation()`.

When I run `MatGetOwnershipRange()`, though, the two PetscInts I get for the beginning and end of the range are both 0.

Does `MatGetOwnershipRange()` only work for MPI matrices?

Does it only work for matrices that have had their values assigned with `MatSetValues()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for any matrix that has had its size set, returning the ownership range of a `Vec` that can be the result of a matrix-vector product. For most matrix types, this matches the row-based storage, though that is not strictly necessary. For sequential matrices, the ownership range is all the rows.